# Submit form wont submit data to database

Tags: php, mysql, submit

I've been trying all night to get this done and have no luck whatsoever. For some reason the form submits, but the data doesn't get sent to the database.
Heres the PHP portion

```
<?php 

mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
if ( isset ( $_POST['Submit'] ) ) //If submit is hit
{
   $name = $_POST['name'];  
   $category = $_POST['category'];  
   $class = $_POST['class'];  
   $level = $_POST['level'];  
   $bind = $_POST['bind'];  
   $tier = $_POST['tier'];  
   $trade = $_POST['trade'];  
   $ilvl = $_POST['ilvl'];  
   $amod = $_POST['amod'];  
   $xdmg = $_POST['xdmg'];  
   $description = $_POST['description'];  
   $description2 = $_POST['description2'];  
   $description3 = $_POST['description3'];  
   $sprice = $_POST['sprice'];  
   $bprice = $_POST['bprice'];  
   $percent = $_POST['percent'];  
   $source = $_POST['source'];  
   $tnail = $_POST['tnail'];  
   $result=MYSQL_QUERY("INSERT INTO items (name, category, class, level, bind, tier, trade, ilvl, amod, xdmg, description, description2, description3, sprice, bprice, percent, source, tnail)".
   "VALUES ( '$name', '$category', '$class', '$level', '$bind', '$tier', '$trade', '$ilvl', '$amod', '$xdmg', '$description', '$description2', '$description3', '$sprice', '$bprice', '$percent', '$source', '$tnail' )")or die( "<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Unable to select table</span></p>");
   mysql_close();
   //confirm
   echo "<p><span style=\"color: red;\">Thank You; the items have been entered in the database. DO NOT REFRESH THE PAGE or data will be sent again.</span></p>"; 
}
else
{
   // close php so we can put in our code
?>
```

Any help?

Comment: Wow, never heard of SQL Injection ?

Comment: Is your "MYSQL_QUERY" all in capitals?

Comment: @WaynnLue that doesn't matter.

Comment: This is a mess. Isolate the specific problem and submit a more focused question.

Comment: What does `mysql_error()` show?

Comment: I'm pretty new to this. I can't isolate any specific problem because I never receive any errors. When I hit submit on my form it works fine but the database never gets updated.

Comment: Could this be an html problem instead of a php problem? mysql_error() shows nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try to close your field names like (`name`, `category`  ... etc.

Answer (score 0):

Place the following code anywhere after calling `mysql_query()`.

```
echo mysql_error();
```

It will show you if anything is wrong with your query or database credentials.